# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'billId' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1054

Though there are many questions asked similar to this. It is quite different than others. And I was not able to get the way to rectify the exact error. That's why posting it here.

Im writing a query where I need to delete entries on multiple tables using one ID.

I have estimation_id. I want to delete bill table also the bill_details table.In bill_details tbl there is bill_id stored.So I wrote a query to select from the bill tbl.But that ended up in error while using it in where clause.

The stored procedure is here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_by_estimation_no`(in_estimation_id int)
BEGIN
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

select (id)projId from projects WHERE estimation_no=in_estimation_id; 
DELETE FROM projects WHERE estimation_no=in_estimation_id; 

DELETE FROM estimation WHERE id=in_estimation_id; 
DELETE FROM estimation_details WHERE estimation_id=in_estimation_id;

select (id)billId from bill where estimation=in_estimation_id;
DELETE FROM bill WHERE estimation=in_estimation_id; 
DELETE FROM bill_details WHERE bill_id=billId; 

select (id)invoiceId from invoice where estimation=in_estimation_id;
DELETE FROM invoice WHERE estimation_no=in_estimation_id; 
DELETE FROM invoice_details WHERE invoice_id=invoiceId; 
 
select (id)crId from change_request where project_id=projId;
DELETE FROM change_request WHERE project_id=projId; 
DELETE FROM change_request_details WHERE cr_id=crId; 

END
```

Im getting this error.

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'billId' in 'where clause'

```
[![Bill][1]][1]
```

[image: Bill details]

[image: projects]

Comment: Can you please add let us know the schema as well?]

Comment: Thank you. Use bill_id instead of billId.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a column  billId in bill_details but you could delete from two table with just a query

```
    DELETE bill, bill_details
    FROM bill 
    INNER JOIN bill_details ON bill.id = bill_details.bill_id
```

(assuming that the join keys are id and bill_id)

Comment: I need to delete the complete row